# Data format for 'Create Space Time Cube From Defined Locations' in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-pro, space-time-cube

I'm trying to figure out the way to structure data for `Create Space Time Cube From Defined Locations` tool in ArcGIS Pro 2.3 ([docs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/createcubefromdefinedlocations.htm)). My raw data sits in text files and is handled in R. I'm working with monthly events in set of locations (that do not change. I've tried help and tutorials online but still fail to understand what the desired input data for this tool is.

Should that be a shape file / feature class with one row per location and columns of attributes representing time? Or does each location x time combination require separate row in dataset? In what format should I store my dates to be readable by Arc?

Answer (score 1):

Simple csv file with code of location, start & end dates, coordinates plus data does the job:

```
code,start,end,lat,lon,value
101021007,2018-01-01,2018-01-31,149.7,-35.4, 100
```